# Pass user id through select box list laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to pass the selected user id to controller from select box.How can I achieve it?

```
{!! route('approve', ['id' => $user->id]) !!}
```

In select box,

```
 {{ Form::select('Actions', [
'approve' => 'Approve',
'decline' => 'Decline']
    ) }}
```

My resulto to be like this,
[image]

Comment: Your form must contain an element for selecting user id. The element must have a name. Then the user id can be read in the controller by accessing the request variable. I strongly suggest you read some Laravel tutorial.

Comment: @Matey How 'ld I change the code

Answer (score 0):

First of all you'll need an input for selecting users. For example I got a list of users with their username and id here :

```
$users= \App\Users::pluck('username','id');
```

after sending it to the view, you can use an input for selecting user :

```
{!! Form::select('user_id', $users,'0', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

That's it. Now you can select the user and get data as $_POST['user_id'] or $_GET['user_id'] in the action. gl.